# Laravel VueJS - Input value array returns strings instead of array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

The title may be confusing but I will explain. Within my VueJS component I have an array called `selectedProducts = []`. I add products to the array with the click of a button and I can do regular things like looping through it.

I add product to the array using the push method. `this.selectedProducts.push(product);`

I want to pass that specific array to the value of a input field so I can send it with the form. Like this

`<input type="hidden" :value="selectedProducts" name="selectedProducts[]">`

But something weird is happening because when I want to access the array within my PHP controller I get this response

`Array ( [0] => [object Object],[object Object] )`

And `is_array($request->array[0])` returns false

Normally you should be able to access the objects and its values but instead these are strings? When I want to do `$request->selectedProducts[0]` or `$request->selectedProducts[0][0]` I can't because it is a string?

```
 print_r($request->selectedProducts); // Returns Array ( [0] => [object Object],[object Object] )
 print(gettype($request->selectedProducts[0])); // Returns "["
 dd(is_array($request->selectedProducts[0])); // Returns false
```

What is happening here? Why can't I access my data within the controller?

Comment: At the bottom level, all input information is transferred as strings. A value of an HTML input cannot be a JS object. So what your code is doing here is storing the best it can - a string representation of what it received. Simply naming an input `something[]` doesn't allow you to store an array into it. You need either multiple inputs where you'll assign individual values from your array or perhaps JSON encode the entire array to use as a value of the single element, then decode it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop through all the products and return

```
<input type="hidden" :value="selectedProducts[index]" name="selectedProducts[]">
```

and then maybe add some identifier to the array like

```
<input type="hidden" :value="selectedProducts[index]" name="selectedProducts[`${product.id}`]">
```

Comment: When I do `selectedProduct[index]` It returns `[object Object],[object Object]` as a String. It shouldn't be necessary to add a ID to the name right? It should just pass the array as an array to the controller if I'm not mistaken. Also whenever I have 50 entries I have 50 fields all with a different name.